# How to update Xcode Command Line Tools to version 2347

Tags: xcode, version

I had installed three different versions of `xcode.app`.
Firstly I uninstalled all `xcode.app`s and removed the related files, but using the following commands

```
xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2345.1.
```

`xcode-select` returns that it already exists.
Then I install `xcode.app` version 8.3.3 and get the following message:

> xcode-select version has not update

`xcode-select -p` returns

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Entering `xcode-select --install` requires me to install.
But when I click on `install`, it shows me

> could not update

and so on messages...

Comment: From Review: I attempted to improve the formatting and the flow of text. I also changed the title a little. Nevertheless, this question probably needs further editing.